# IPv6 scope id problem with IE and ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, identity, ipv6

Setup:

> Two W2K3 machines in domain with IPv6 installed on both.  App is on Machine #1.

What works with IE8:

> Machine #2 can log into the app using IPv4 address (http://192.168.../app)
>   Machine #2 can log into the app using machine name (http://machine1name/app)
>   Machine #1 can log into the app using IPv4 address, machine name, and localhost.
>   Machine #1 can log into the app using local IPv6 address (without scope-id).
>   Machine #1 can log into the app using network IPv6 address (without scope-id).

What doesn't work with IE8, **BUT** works with Firefox:

> Machine #2 can't log into the app using network IPv6 address of Machine #1 (with scope-id).

**ORIGINAL ISSUE**:  I've tried to narrow down the problem.  I can bring up the login page and enter my credentials.  In code, I check Active Directory for authentication, and the user does get authenticated.  However, the `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` is never set.  It should be set when I call `RedirectFromLoginPage(username)`, and it is when Machine #2 uses IPv4 to access the app.  However, when I use the IPv6 address, `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` is always blank.

The authentication and application work fine when using IPv4, so I don't think it's a code issue, but not sure?  Or is there some network/IE setting I need to adjust?

**EDIT**:  Firefox with IPv6 and IE8 with IPv4 have no problem creating an authentication cookie.  For some reason, IE8 with IPv6 cannot create the cookie, hence, the problem with RedirectFromLoginPage, which is supposed to create the cookie.

**EDIT 2**:  The problem seems to be the `%` in the IPv6 address when using IE [ie. the scope-id].  For example, with Firefox, you can have the `%` in the address with no problem.  With IE, if you are accessing an app locally using IPv6 (whether local or network IP), you can leave out the scope-id.  However, when accessing an app on a network machine, you need the scope-id.  And since 
you have to encode the `%` with `%25`, that's where the problem is.

[ps. I know [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961315/redirectfromloginpage-is-not-updating-user-identity-name) has a similar title, but it's not the same problem.]

Answer (score 0):

Quite honestly, the best way to solve this is to not use link-local addresses as web endpoints. As you have discovered, this area of IPv6 is ill-defined.

I would recommend using static IPv6 addresses instead. Either that, or have your network administrator (you?) enable IPv6 router advertisements on your subnet so you can get "real" (**not** link-local) IPv6 addresses.

Note, you can still use "private" IPv6 space (like you're doing with 192.168.0.0/16 IPv4 addresses)

If you don't have a "real" IPv6 subnet, you could either use a /64 subnet numbered for [6to4](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/6to4) (which might be good if you have a real IPv4 address and you [eventually] want your hosts to participate on the "real" IPv6 internet) or get a [unique local](http://www.sixxs.net/tools/grh/ula/) subnet to use.

Or just go for it and broker a 6in4 tunnel from a place like [Hurricane Electric](http://tunnelbroker.net/).